# Caching dynamic image generated on php

Tags: php

My php script parses user's profile on other site, takes some info and generates .png image with it for certain user (script.php?username=). Each time page with these images is loaded, script runs again and again.
How can I cache images and only run script again if information it outputs was changed? It would save pretty much resources.

Comment: Sorry to say this now, but i'm a total noob and I don't understand many things you tell me. Thanks for information though, I hope google will do now.
I also have nginx and not apache, so .htaccess won't work, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Judging from most of the answer, I think you want to extend the part about recreating the image if the user's information has changed. Your question is misunderstood to only refer to simple image caching mechanics.

Comment: So I decided to recreate image only when 24 hours had passed after last creation. Thanks to all users for help!

Comment: Then you should upvote any answers that you found helpful and accept the one you found to be most correct for you. That's how we thank each other on SO :)

Comment: I would be glad to, but I haven't enough rep yet :P
Checked one answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the user's profile again on each request to find out if something has changed.

You can then throw all the information into some kind of hash like `md5($name.$location)` and store this information anywhere. If you now get a request for an image, parse the user's profile, create the hash again and look this hash up. If you have stored it, you previously created the image and can just output it. If the hash is different, the user's information has changed, as well and you will have to recreate the image.

You can also apply some heuristic like the fact that a user might only change his profile once an hour, or even only once a day. With this assumption you can compare the creation date of the user's image and only parse the user's information if the image is older than an hour (or day).

Comment: That's quite a good idea to store images for 24 hours (for example) and update them as time expires. I think I will go this way, it's not so important to me to have real-time changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Cache the image to disk and let Apache take care of the rest.**

First, redo your image URI's so they are similar to:

```
<img src="/images/profiles/johnsmith.png" />
```

Then, in the `/images/profiles/`, place a `.htaccess` file with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ /script.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then have your script write the resulting png to disk before serving it to the user. Next time the image is requested, it will get it directly from the web server.

When the user's profile info changes, simply delete the existing .png file from the server and your script will be run the next time the image is requested.

If you don't want the web server to be able to write within the web root, write outside of it and have a cron job move them.

Answer (score 3):

Caching images is probably the easiest caching problem to solve as it is just a matter of saving a local copy of any image to your server after it is generated and checking for a local copy before running the code that generates it.

Something like:-

```
if(file_exists(image12345.png && !checkIfDataChanged()){
    serve cached file;
} else {
    generate new file;
    save new file to image12345.png;
    serve cached file;
}
```

This pseudo-code ofcourse, but it should be easy enough for you to translate it into PHP.

Comment: To quote OP `How can I cache images and only run script again if information it outputs was changed?`. The user's information will change over time so the images will have to be re-created.

Comment: @Basti Oh yes, edited. In your solution, would using the hash as a file name work?

Comment: Possibly yes. But you couldn't correlate the username with it's image anymore without first parsing his profile.

Answer (score 2):

set the php headers to inform the browser that the resource is cached :

```
header("Last-Modified: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", getlastmod()));
```

Answer (score 2):

here, you can find how can you cache images using php.
You can call these script when you find update from database, otherwise every time image will be load from cache.

```
// put this above any php image generation code:
session_start(); 
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 2 day")));
```

https://dtbaker.net/blog/web-development/2009/06/how-to-cache-images-generated-by-php/

Comment: Hello, can you please update your link ? The one you posted is now dead.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Updated.