# Caching a php script on browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the following barcode generating script to generate barcodes for my system.

https://github.com/davidscotttufts/php-barcode

It works pretty much well on localhost and hosting, but when network get slows, the barcode image is not loading. So is there any way to cache this script on users browser? Or is there any efficient way?

Comment: PHP only runs on the server so no, you cannot cache it in the browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caching dynamic image generated on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691473/caching-dynamic-image-generated-on-php)

Comment: @ADyson Any alternatives? Can I add that php script to the calling page itself?

Comment: @DarkBee no, I just need to fastly access the script, not the generated image. Coz sometimes I need to create 5 images by using a loop.

Comment: `Can I add that php script to the calling page itself`...it's not clear what you mean. What calling page, exactly? How are you running the PHP script currently? If there was another PHP script calling it, then presumably you've already added the barcode generator to that script via an `include` or `require`? Unless you're calling it via a secondary HTTP request (e.g. using curl or something)? It's hard to tell what you're trying to ask, without context.